# Why does My app stops after i press the button

Tags: java, android-studio

this is how i have registered the users..but it is not sending anything to database though the registration completes just fine

```
private void registerUser(){



        //getting email and password from edit texts
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password  = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        //checking if email and passwords are empty
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        //if the email and password are not empty
        //displaying a progress dialog

        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();


        //creating a new user
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        //checking if success
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
                        }else{
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

    }
```

then here is my login.activity. i can log in just fine but i wonder what cretiria is this code using to log in users??

```
private void userLogin(){
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password  = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();


    //checking if email and passwords are empty
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    //if the email and password are not empty
    //displaying a progress dialog

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");
    progressDialog.show();

    //logging in the user
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    //if the task is successfull
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        //start the profile activity
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: stack trace? is it a specifiec button?

Comment: post the logcat error

Comment: yes @MordenachayS here is my mainactivity.xml file

Comment: where can i get the logcat error please??

Comment: click on android monitor button in the bottom of android studio

Comment: 11-22 19:45:40.501 588-1490/system_process W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000

Comment: open your app and monitor the logcat then when it crashed copy the error and paste here

Comment: problem resides in your Person class , check whether it has a default constructor , if not create one

Comment: please just write that code for me, I am new to java, Please Umar Ata

Comment: public Person() {
      
    } // i did this, is it correct??

Comment: @UmarAta  what do you have to say about this com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.example.moses.bstation.Person] from String value; no single-String constructor/factory method

Comment: @MordechayS what about this error, can you help me solve it,                       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.example.moses.bstation.Person] from String value; no single-String constructor/factory method

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your person class like this

```
    public class Person {

    private String Username;
    private String Email;

    public Person(String email,String userName) {
     this.Username=userName;
     this.Email=email;

      /*Blank default constructor essential for Firebase*/
    }
    //Getters and setters
    public String getUsername() {
        return Username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String Username) {
        this.Username = Username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String Email) {
        this.Email = Email;
    }
}
```

then use it like this

```
 Person person=new Person();
 person.setUsername(Username);
 person.setEmail(Email);
 Firebase newRef = ref.child("Users").push();
 newRef.setValue(person);
```

then use this to get values

```
 newRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
               Person person = dataSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);
 String string = "Username: "+person.getName()+"\nEmail: "+person.getEmail()+"\n\n";

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: the problem is still there...data is sent to firebase properly but the program stops imediately after that...@UmarAta

Comment: 11-22 21:14:15.522 30892-30892/com.example.moses.bstation E/UncaughtException: com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
                                                                                   at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:185)
                                                                                   at com.example.moses.bstation.MainActivity$1$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:57)

Comment: thanks @UmarAta the  ref.addValueEventListener  was the problem..its running fine now..thanks for your effort bro

Comment: Click on green check in the top left corner of my answer to accept it

Comment: Hey @UmarAta i voted your answer but i do not have enough reputation to record it...

Comment: thats okay , you can click on check just below the voting buttons

Comment: i have a new error by the way, i was able to register users and log them in but when i check database, no records are found but when i use the same credentials i used to register in my login it works??  what am i missing?? @UmarAta

Comment: are you using anonymous login

Comment: firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

Comment: when using different users are getting any error from firebase

Comment: this is not correct, if you have another question ask it as a new question , don't override your previous question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described here:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   instantiate value of type [simple type, class
>   com.example.moses.bstation.Person] from String value; no single-String
>   constructor/factory method

It seems that the mapping between the **JSON response** and the **Person** class is incorrect.

Double check your Person class implementation, also please share your Person class implementation and a sample from the JSON response.

Comment: the data is sent to my firebase correctly, but after that the app stops